# Why `sys.path` differs when executed in mod_wsgi and normal interpreter mode?

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

Environment:

`MAC OS 10.10.4
python 2.7.12 with pyenv
mod_wsgi 3.4
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)`

I have a wsgi.py that print the sys.path:

```
import sys
print sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, '...')

from app import app as application
```

and I confirmed that during installing `mod_wsgi`, it is configured with the correct python version (**/Users/forever/.pyenv/shims/python**: installed by `pyenv`):

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.4.10
checking for python... /Users/forever/.pyenv/shims/python
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

then configure Apache with following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerName loyal.jms.tw

    # WSGIPythonHome /Users/forever/.pyenv/shims
    WSGIDaemonProcess test user=forever group=admin threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/forever/git/test/app/wsgi.py

    <Directory /Users/forever/git/test/app>
        WSGIProcessGroup test
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache log shows the `mod_wsgi` information which has correct python version configured :

```
[Tue May 30 13:59:28.658723 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4843] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.24 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Then weird part is that the `sys.path` output in Apache log:

```
['/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

which seems like the python path of system default python, not the python I installed by `pyenv`. Then I check what the `sys.path` is with the python interpreter installed by `pyenv`, it shows:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, May 26 2017, 21:30:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/forever/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

, which is different.

I would like to know how can this happen? and how to correct the python path used by mod_wsgi?

Comment: You haven't configured WSGI to use your virtualenv, see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Why are you using mod_wsgi 3.4, that version is ancient. Are you trying to use the version from ``Server.app``? Recommended you do not do that. And either way, if mod_wsgi is compiled for different Python installation, you can't force it to use Python virtual environment based on another. See ``pip install`` method. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: Also, ``pyenv`` produces Python installations which by default are broken and cannot be used with embedded systems. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/392

Answer (score 0):

WSGI has not been configured to use your virtualenv Python. See the [documentation on WSGI and virtualenv](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html); you need to configure the daemon process group to use the right binary:

```
# add the python-home argument here
WSGIDaemonProcess test python-home=/Users/forever/.pyenv/shims user=forever group=admin threads=5
```

Otherwise, as the documentation states:

> As only the single application is being run within the daemon process group, the `WSGIApplicationGroup` directive is also being used. **When this is used with the `%{GLOBAL}` value, it forces the WSGI application to run in the main Python interpreter context of each process.**

Bold emphasis mine.

`WSGIPythonHome` should only be used in embedded mode (no `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` directives).

Comment: After adding `python-home=/Users/forever/.pyenv/shim` and restart, there are many lines of  `ImportError: No module named site` in Apache err log

Comment: @LucasYang: sounds like a Python version incompatibility, see [Django Apache and Virtualenv ImportError: No module named site](//stackoverflow.com/q/41005030)

Comment: @LucasYang: there are a few other posts about using WSGI with a virtualenv throwing that exception, I suggest a quick Google search and see if any of those match.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that post, but I use the same python version for compiling mod_wsgi and configure the virtual host in Apache. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: That's why I suggested further google searching; it may be that the Python home is set wrong?